# Mac OSX で OpenCV を import cv2で呼び出せない。

Tags: python, macos, opencv, python3

下記の様なエラーが出ます。同様のエラーが出てる様なのですが、具体的な対処法をお教え頂けませんか？

```
S's-MacBook-Air:site-packages xxx$ python3
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

OpenCV は下記の様にインストールしました。

```
$ brew install homebrew/science/opencv3 --with-python3 --HEAD
```

Comment: 下記の様にインストールしました。$ brew install homebrew/science/opencv3 --with-python3 --HEAD

Comment: 使用している python は anaconda のようですね。これに対し、OpenCV のインストールは brew で行なっているのが原因だと思います。おそらく、brew 側の python3 には cv2 がインストールされているのではないでしょうか。（Mac の事はあまり解らないので、詳しい回答は書けません）

Comment: $ python3  のコマンドで勝手にanacondaを呼び出すのですが、brewでのpythonの呼び出しは別の呼び出し方になるのでしょうか？